# What happens when this situation occurs in Tsuro?

Tags: end-game, tsuro

There are two empty sepetated spaces left and the person going does not have a card to play but the next person does.

Does the first person lose because they are out of cards to play or does the second player lose because they still have a card to play afterwards that will move them off the board?

Comment: I don't think this should count as a duplicate, even though your short "it's impossible" answer with a link to that other question does handle this. The questions are (on their face at least) very different, and the answer to this one does/can include information that does not appear in that one: that under proper play, by the time one person is trying to play from an empty hand, all other hands are also empty and there is one space left. (This _could_ be added to the other, but it isn't directly relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to get into that situation.

Please review [how to handle](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/203/2880) the situation when you run out of cards.

Comment: I would like to post a picture but it says its to big.

Comment: Feel free to email the photo to ikegami@adaelis.com, and I'll add it to your question. That said, a picture won't help because your description of the scenario was quite clear. It's just not possible to get into that situation if you followed the rules.